# Any idea or suggestions related to configurations of Rundeck's "Run a script to produce resource model data"

Tags: rundeck

I have python script that stores results in dictionary and i want that node data results in rundeck, can i get any suggestions/solutions ? the option what i need to make use of is "Run a script to produce resource model data"

Answer (score 0):

That model source needs an script that generates an valid [XML](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/resource-v13.html#resource-xml)/[YAML](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/resource-yaml-v13.html#resource-yaml) Rundeck model source format, i.e.:

```py
from xml.dom import minidom
import os 
  
  
root = minidom.Document()
  
xml = root.createElement('project') 
root.appendChild(xml)
  
productChild = root.createElement('node')
productChild.setAttribute('name', 'node00')
productChild.setAttribute('description', 'my description')
productChild.setAttribute('tags', 'db,testsrv')
productChild.setAttribute('hostname', '10.0.0.12')
productChild.setAttribute('osArch', 'unix')
productChild.setAttribute('osName', 'Linux')
productChild.setAttribute('osVersion', '6.0.9')
productChild.setAttribute('username', 'vagrant')
productChild.setAttribute('ssh-key-storage-path', 'keys/rundeck')
  
xml.appendChild(productChild)
  
xml_str = root.toprettyxml(indent ="\t") 
  
print(xml_str)
```

Of course, you can replace the elements by your script generated data (my example just put strings there).

Then, the model sources needs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg1cG.jpg) config to get that data. Basically: The "Resource Format" is the script generated data (XML or YAML, XML in the example), "Script File Path" is the path to your python script, "Interpreter" is the full path to the python interpreter (python3 in my case), and "Argument" is only if your script is designed with external arguments.

See the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yLFE.jpg).

Comment: i am also trying with yaml format but i get this error, any suggestion on how to debug ?

```The Node Source had an error:
failed to execute: /home/rundeck/nodes_collector.py: Script execution failed with result: 1```

Comment: Just create your script and test it on python directly before use it on Rundeck (them, make sure to use the right script path/interpreter in the model source). That's the best way to debug it.

Comment: when i execute script it gives me clear output, for ex:

`- db01:
   hostname: db01
   nodename: db01
   description: ''
   username: harshakumar
   ssh-key-storage-path: keys/ssh_pass/key
   ssh-authentication: privateKey
   osFamily: unix
   tags:  DB servers`

Comment: the output will respect the yaml format, the main problem of that format is that is column sensitvie, probably you need a parser in your script, that's a python dev issue.